# simple go binary deployment on server not working

Tags: ubuntu, go

I have configured it on my manjaro linux with go version "go1.11.5 linux/amd64". The following program builds into binary and that binary works inside my go folder and inside my home folder directly.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
}
```

Once it was running on my local system I decided to upload this binary using ftp to remote ubuntu 18.04 server. I have copied the binary on server home folder. chmod 755 on it to make it executable. chown to change user to currently logged in user of server. installed go version "go1.11 linux/amd64" on server. When I try to execute binary it give me following exception

```
Segmentation fault
```

let me know what else I need to share to make this work. I have another project built with gin and lots of other packages. that binary I need to configure to serve api on this same server. since thats not working I decided to go with this dead simple binary and to my surprise this isn't working.

let me post go env for both systems, local and remote.

```
go env on local 
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/najam/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/najam/go"
GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build859876677=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

go env on ubuntu server

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/myuser/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/myuser/go"
GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build276202541=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Comment: There's no reason to install Go on the server, if you're compiling the code elsewhere. Having said that, compiling it on the server would probably solve your problem.

Comment: Make sure the architecture matches: Did you create a 64bit executable but your system is 32bit?

Comment: @Flimzy thanks for edit and response. that awesome if you dont need to install go.  just wow. i dont want to compile again on server because that means installing all the dependencies dont want that.

Comment: @Volker i have updated question with goenv settings.  but with down votes i dont know if i use this platform or simply delete question.

Comment: This shows you built a 64bit binary and probably are using a 64bit server. Your problem is most likely totally unrelated to Go but some general server problem and you should start troubleshooting in that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so with super help from golang slack guys. 
i build using

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o najamgo  hello.go
```

before i was using

```
go build hello.go
```

then since i was using ftp i had to change transfer type from "auto or acscii" to "binary". then from that point just chmod on the uploaded file to make it executable.

```
sudo chmod 755 hello
```

finally execute the binary.

```
./hello
```

and its working.

Comment: May be this is the issue 'ftp i had to change transfer type from "auto or acscii" to "binary"'? I guess that the file was corrupted when you transfer it. I suggest to try with the default compilation options and binary file transfer. If this is the issue then it has nothing to do with go compilation process and we can update the answer. Thank you!

Comment: as i was told its file transfer issue with go binary. file transfer binary did the magic. played with .net and nodejs apps never encountered such issue so this was new for me